# Is hook_init the right hook I should use in my case?

Tags: hooks

If I want to override a certain page with drupal_set_title() is hook_init the right hook to use?

Same thing with adding a js script on a certain page with drupal_add_js() is hook_init the right hook as well?

Comment: I don't understand what the title is meant to say.

Comment: If the page is controlled with Page manager you can set whatever title you want in the UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really depends on what you want to achieve... If you want to alter several pages the [page title module](https://drupal.org/project/page_title) might be better suited. Using a combination of this module and your own could lead to your code in hook_init() being overwritten. But it does not have to happen.

The more modules you have, the later you want to interfere with everything as more modules might try altering your outputs. So in those cases hook_init might not be the right place.

If you want to add JavaScript to your own custom module you might also add it in the module.info file. This usually works better with aggregations.

Update:

You could use any page hook, for instance [hook_view()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_view/7) like this:

```
mymodule_view($node, $view_mode) {
  if($node->nid == 1) { // Act only if this node id (nid) is requested
     drupal_set_title("title");
     ...
  }
}
```

Comment: I am trying to alter the title of only one page. A module for that is kind of overkill.

Comment: As for the js the problem with module.info is the same concern I have for hook_init. It initializes on every page when I only need the js to be included on one page.

Comment: see my updated answer.

Comment: So another follow up with your comment. So using drupal_add_js does not work with aggregation? Same thing with drupal_add_css?

Comment: I've had situation where it didn't... However if it only affects one page, it should not be such an issue. To maximize performance you could minify it if you require this.

Comment: I didn't realized this should've been two separate questions. Sorry about that. So hook_init is alright for adding js I will just use strpos and $_SERVER to target specific page?

Comment: Add your js/css as a new question and someone with more experience might help you on those ones. I can't tell for sure. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Using a hook or a module for altering the page title of a single page is IMHO overkill.

When I want to override the title or some other feature on a specific page, I usually use the override feature of the Drupal template system.

For instance, to override the node template for `node/42`, I create `node--42.tpl.php` by copying the default [`node.tpl.php`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.tpl.php/7) (this is the D7 naming convention), place the copy in my theme's `templates/` directory, and then edit it to hold any modifications (including `$title`) that I want to make to that particular page.

Remember to flush caches to see the effect when you're overriding a template!